# eclipselink get another jdbc connection in same transaction

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

My pseudo code is like below using EclipseLink:

```
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();       //0
    create orders                                 //1
    customerEntity.getOrders().add(orderEntity);  //2
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();      //3
```

The problem is at #2, EclipseLink gets a different connection from #1 which ends up two connections in one transaction (and thread), this cause deadlock in my app.

I googled that eclipselink might use different pool for read and write. Is it still true? Why eclipselink tries to get another connection, how to avoid deadlock I encountered ?

Comment: How are you getting your customerEntity, and how is use of a read connection causing a deadlock?

Comment: My customerEntity is get from this entityManager, and I could not find other entityManager related in above code. The deadlock is because when calling create orders, conn#1 will insert into DB, but will not commit until #3. At #2, another connection will read from DB (maybe a table scan), this will block because insert is not committed yet.

Comment: I am surprised because if EclipseLink detects it is within a transaction and changes have been made, I was under the impression reads would use the write connection so that it would see changes made in the transaction.  How are you creating orders and are you calling em.flush?  What versions are used?  And any reason you have not chosen other database settings so that reads aren't blocked by transactions, as it seems like it would really hinder performance and increase the likelihood of deadlock when traversing any relation inside a transaction.